# firefly freenas 8.2 with iTunes

Tags: itunes, plugins, freebsd, freenas

I'm trying to get Firefly Version svn-1696 to work on Freenas 8.2 with iTunes (latest)... I've installed everything correctly and it seems to work.  I have a working mount point so that the jailed plugin can see the correct Music directory, the mount point works perfectly but I can't get firefly to populate the mp3s in the folder. iTunes can see Firefly and I can use Firefly's UI but when I scan, it comes up with 0 files.

Is there a specific file structure I need to follow?  I tried just throwing a few folders with mp3s and dumping my iTunes library but neither works.  It doesn't find a single MP3.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I followed the [FreeNAS Plugins](http://doc.freenas.org/index.php/Plugins) documentation and I was having the same issue of FireFly reporting "Songs 0". I could not figure it out until I looked at the firefly output log, located here:

```
/mnt/volume1/jail/software/var/log/mt-daapd.log
```

where it reported:

> 2012-09-03 03:00:06 (18a217af): Rescanning database 2012-09-03
>   03:00:06 (18a217af): opendir: No such file or directory 2012-09-03
>   03:00:06 (18a217af): Starting playlist scan 2012-09-03 03:00:06
>   18a217af): Updating playlists 2012-09-03 03:00:08 (18a217af): Error
>   rescanning... bad path?

I finally remembered FireFly lives in a jail and I had manually (incorrectly) changed the path of the "Mp3 dir:" FireFly plugin option to point to a different dataset that lives outside of the jail, so FireFly was unaware of the path.

I ended up setting the "Mp3 dir:" to: **/mnt/volume1/jail/software/media**

The plugin setting will display **/media** after you select the directory since it's a directory in the jail root. I then setup a NFS share to transfer the Mp3s into the directory.

After restarting the FireFly plugin service, FireFly successfully scanned the mp3s and is showing up in iTunes along with all the of the songs.

I also removed the recommended 2GB quota for the jail since I do not want a size restriction, as my mp3s will live in there.

I am using the following versions:

- FreeNAS-8.3.0-BETA1-x64 (r12054)
- firefly-1696_7-amd64